# How do I get the substring matched by a named capture group?

Tags: regex, perl

The simple regex `(?<nom>\d)` makes the content of the matched digit directly available as captured group `$1`.

This captured group also has the name `nom` - is this also directly available in Perl? Or must I do this assignment myself, by writing `$nom = $1`?

Comment: The whole point of named captures is to have that, yes; it's `$+{nom}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups:

> Capture group contents are dynamically scoped and available to you outside the pattern until the end of the enclosing block or until the next successful match, whichever comes first. (See [Compound Statements in perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements).) **You can refer to them** by absolute number (using `"$1"` instead of `"\g1"` , etc); or **by name via the `%+` hash, using `"$+{name}"`**. [emphasis mine]

So the notation is `$+{nom}` rather than `$nom` (but you can always write `$nom = $+{nom}` if you really want).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @TonyR: You're welcome!